# Python print doesn't show in async function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

My code doesn't output any text, and then terminates after 5 seconds. Doing so in a non-async method does show output, but blocks other processes from running. Any thoughts and/or suggestions?

```py
import asyncio, os, sys, time

def update(text):
    # Area of interest
    global print
    print("", flush=True)
    os.system("clear")
    print(text, flush=True)
    print("What is your selection? ", flush=True)

async def main():
    a = "a"
    while True:
        update(a)
        a += "c"
        time.sleep(0.05)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main())
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: don't interweave async and sync functions interdependently

Comment: What do you mean by that, @RomanPerekhrest?

Comment: Take a look how async coroutines should be defined (offic. docs)

Comment: What is the purpose of `global print`?

Comment: An `async` function needs to be awaited, otherwise it doesn’t do anything.

Comment: @JohnGordon, `global print` was my attempt at fixing this problem, and @deceze, how do I await an async function in the global scope?

Comment: Async isn’t multi-threading. The async function does not execute in parallel “in the background”, as you seem to think.

Comment: `main` is async, which means *other* asynchronous could be "interleaved" with `main`, but main itself *blocks* any other function from being schedule until it is complete. You would want to use `asyncio.wait` instead of `time.sleep` at the very least.

Comment: Replace `loop.create_task(main())` with `asyncio.run(main())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code in `main` itself never runs - you don´t call the event loop:

while `asyncio.create_task` will create a task and get it running "in the background" when you are *already* running asynchronous code, that never happens in this example:

Your modulelevel code gets a reference to an event loop, with `get_event_loop`, but uses `create_task(main())`  - that will create a task to run the main function, but you then never switch control to the asyncio event loop itself.

A more proper way isto have your synchronous code define things up to the point everything is ready, and then pass the control to the event loop so that it executes a "parent" task that may or not spawn others.

In recent Python versions, this is simply done with `asyncio.run()` - with no need to get an explicit reference to the loop prior to that. In older Python one would have to call `get_event_loop()` as you do, and would usually call `loop.run_until_complete(main())`.

There are other strange things in your code - including the use of `os.system` just to clear the screen - just print the ANSI sequence `"\x1b[2J" on Unixes, or` print("\n" * 70)` in any system.

The other thing is that you should use `await asyncio.sleep(...)` when using asyncio code, and never `time.sleep`

```
import asyncio
...

async def main():
    a = "a"
    while True:
        update(a)
        a += "c"
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

asyncio.run(main())
```